# Swift json format error

Tags: json, swift, format

When I tried to obtain the json information using the autocomplete of wunderground, the json information that I retrieved seemed to be in a wrong format. I used the swift code below to receive the json information.

```
let urlPath = "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=lon"    
let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
if error != nil {
    println(error)
} else {
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    println(json)
}
```

The output is

```
{
RESULTS =     (
            {
        c = GB;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.1.03772";
        lat = "51.480000";
        ll = "51.480000 -0.450000";
        lon = "-0.450000";
        name = "London, United Kingdom";
        type = city;
        tz = "Europe/London";
        tzs = BST;
        zmw = "00000.1.03772";
    },
            {
        c = US;
        l = "/q/zmw:90745.1.99999";
        lat = "33.826080";
        ll = "33.826080 -118.262222";
        lon = "-118.262222";
        name = "Long Beach, California";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/Los_Angeles";
        tzs = PDT;
        zmw = "90745.1.99999";
    },
            {
        c = BR;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.1.83766";
        lat = "-23.379999";
        ll = "-23.379999 -51.180000";
        lon = "-51.180000";
        name = "Londrina, Brazil";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/Sao_Paulo";
        tzs = BRT;
        zmw = "00000.1.83766";
    },
            {
        c = CA;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.1.71623";
        lat = "43.029999";
        ll = "43.029999 -81.150002";
        lon = "-81.150002";
        name = "London, Canada";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/Montreal";
        tzs = EDT;
        zmw = "00000.1.71623";
    },
            {
        c = CA;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.3.WCWVZ";
        lat = "45.531216";
        ll = "45.531216 -73.518059";
        lon = "-73.518059";
        name = "Longueuil, Canada";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/Montreal";
        tzs = EDT;
        zmw = "00000.3.WCWVZ";
    },
            {
        c = IN;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.12.42182";
        lat = "28.750000";
        ll = "28.750000 77.283333";
        lon = "77.283333";
        name = "Loni, India";
        type = city;
        tz = "Asia/Kolkata";
        tzs = IST;
        zmw = "00000.12.42182";
    },
            {
        c = CN;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.4.50854";
        lat = "46.549999";
        ll = "46.549999 125.116669";
        lon = "125.116669";
        name = "Longfeng, China";
        type = city;
        tz = "Asia/Harbin";
        tzs = CST;
        zmw = "00000.4.50854";
    },
            {
        c = CN;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.3.WZYYJ";
        lat = "42.771389";
        ll = "42.771389 129.423340";
        lon = "129.423340";
        name = "Longjing, China";
        type = city;
        tz = "Asia/Harbin";
        tzs = CST;
        zmw = "00000.3.WZYYJ";
    },
            {
        c = CN;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.3.50745";
        lat = "47.330276";
        ll = "47.330276 123.183609";
        lon = "123.183609";
        name = "Longjiang, China";
        type = city;
        tz = "Asia/Harbin";
        tzs = CST;
        zmw = "00000.3.50745";
    },
            {
        c = CN;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.1.58647";
        lat = "28.100000";
        ll = "28.100000 119.080002";
        lon = "119.080002";
        name = "Longquan, China";
        type = city;
        tz = "Asia/Shanghai";
        tzs = CST;
        zmw = "00000.1.58647";
    },
            {
        c = GB;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.4.03906";
        lat = "54.997215";
        ll = "54.997215 -7.309170";
        lon = "-7.309170";
        name = "Londonderry County Borough, United Kingdom";
        type = city;
        tz = "Europe/London";
        tzs = BST;
        zmw = "00000.4.03906";
    },
            {
        c = US;
        l = "/q/zmw:80501.1.99999";
        lat = "40.181301";
        ll = "40.181301 -105.102402";
        lon = "-105.102402";
        name = "Longmont, Colorado";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/Denver";
        tzs = MDT;
        zmw = "80501.1.99999";
    },
            {
        c = US;
        l = "/q/zmw:75601.1.99999";
        lat = "32.523197";
        ll = "32.523197 -94.733734";
        lon = "-94.733734";
        name = "Longview, Texas";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/Chicago";
        tzs = CDT;
        zmw = "75601.1.99999";
    },
            {
        c = CN;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.1.54753";
        lat = "37.619999";
        ll = "37.619999 120.320000";
        lon = "120.320000";
        name = "Longkou, China";
        type = city;
        tz = "Asia/Shanghai";
        tzs = CST;
        zmw = "00000.1.54753";
    },
            {
        c = GB;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.30.03418";
        lat = "52.900002";
        ll = "52.900002 -1.266667";
        lon = "-1.266667";
        name = "Long Eaton, United Kingdom";
        type = city;
        tz = "Europe/London";
        tzs = BST;
        zmw = "00000.30.03418";
    },
            {
        c = US;
        l = "/q/zmw:98632.1.99999";
        lat = "46.181339";
        ll = "46.181339 -123.061798";
        lon = "-123.061798";
        name = "Longview, Washington";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/Los_Angeles";
        tzs = PDT;
        zmw = "98632.1.99999";
    },
            {
        c = US;
        l = "/q/zmw:11561.1.99999";
        lat = "40.587124";
        ll = "40.587124 -73.665718";
        lon = "-73.665718";
        name = "Long Beach, New York";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/New_York";
        tzs = EDT;
        zmw = "11561.1.99999";
    },
            {
        c = US;
        l = "/q/zmw:07740.1.99999";
        lat = "40.294498";
        ll = "40.294498 -73.995178";
        lon = "-73.995178";
        name = "Long Branch, New Jersey";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/New_York";
        tzs = EDT;
        zmw = "07740.1.99999";
    },
            {
        c = US;
        l = "/q/zmw:03038.2.99999";
        lat = "42.888672";
        ll = "42.888672 -71.299515";
        lon = "-71.299515";
        name = "Londonderry, New Hampshire";
        type = city;
        tz = "America/New_York";
        tzs = EDT;
        zmw = "03038.2.99999";
    },
            {
        c = AO;
        l = "/q/zmw:00000.9.66318";
        lat = "-12.906667";
        ll = "-12.906667 15.253333";
        lon = "15.253333";
        name = "Longonjo, Angola";
        type = city;
        tz = "Africa/Luanda";
        tzs = WAT;
        zmw = "00000.9.66318";
    }
);
```

I can't understand why all the colons become equal sign here. 
Actually, it should be like this

```
{
"RESULTS": [
    {
        "name": "London, United Kingdom",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "GB",
        "zmw": "00000.1.03772",
        "tz": "Europe/London",
        "tzs": "BST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.03772",
        "ll": "51.480000 -0.450000",
        "lat": "51.480000",
        "lon": "-0.450000"
    },
    {
        "name": "Long Beach, California",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "US",
        "zmw": "90745.1.99999",
        "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "tzs": "PDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:90745.1.99999",
        "ll": "33.826080 -118.262222",
        "lat": "33.826080",
        "lon": "-118.262222"
    },
    {
        "name": "Londrina, Brazil",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "BR",
        "zmw": "00000.1.83766",
        "tz": "America/Sao_Paulo",
        "tzs": "BRT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.83766",
        "ll": "-23.379999 -51.180000",
        "lat": "-23.379999",
        "lon": "-51.180000"
    },
    {
        "name": "London, Canada",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "CA",
        "zmw": "00000.1.71623",
        "tz": "America/Montreal",
        "tzs": "EDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.71623",
        "ll": "43.029999 -81.150002",
        "lat": "43.029999",
        "lon": "-81.150002"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longueuil, Canada",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "CA",
        "zmw": "00000.3.WCWVZ",
        "tz": "America/Montreal",
        "tzs": "EDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.3.WCWVZ",
        "ll": "45.531216 -73.518059",
        "lat": "45.531216",
        "lon": "-73.518059"
    },
    {
        "name": "Loni, India",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "IN",
        "zmw": "00000.12.42182",
        "tz": "Asia/Kolkata",
        "tzs": "IST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.12.42182",
        "ll": "28.750000 77.283333",
        "lat": "28.750000",
        "lon": "77.283333"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longfeng, China",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "CN",
        "zmw": "00000.4.50854",
        "tz": "Asia/Harbin",
        "tzs": "CST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.4.50854",
        "ll": "46.549999 125.116669",
        "lat": "46.549999",
        "lon": "125.116669"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longjing, China",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "CN",
        "zmw": "00000.3.WZYYJ",
        "tz": "Asia/Harbin",
        "tzs": "CST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.3.WZYYJ",
        "ll": "42.771389 129.423340",
        "lat": "42.771389",
        "lon": "129.423340"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longjiang, China",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "CN",
        "zmw": "00000.3.50745",
        "tz": "Asia/Harbin",
        "tzs": "CST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.3.50745",
        "ll": "47.330276 123.183609",
        "lat": "47.330276",
        "lon": "123.183609"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longquan, China",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "CN",
        "zmw": "00000.1.58647",
        "tz": "Asia/Shanghai",
        "tzs": "CST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.58647",
        "ll": "28.100000 119.080002",
        "lat": "28.100000",
        "lon": "119.080002"
    },
    {
        "name": "Londonderry County Borough, United Kingdom",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "GB",
        "zmw": "00000.4.03906",
        "tz": "Europe/London",
        "tzs": "BST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.4.03906",
        "ll": "54.997215 -7.309170",
        "lat": "54.997215",
        "lon": "-7.309170"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longmont, Colorado",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "US",
        "zmw": "80501.1.99999",
        "tz": "America/Denver",
        "tzs": "MDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:80501.1.99999",
        "ll": "40.181301 -105.102402",
        "lat": "40.181301",
        "lon": "-105.102402"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longview, Texas",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "US",
        "zmw": "75601.1.99999",
        "tz": "America/Chicago",
        "tzs": "CDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:75601.1.99999",
        "ll": "32.523197 -94.733734",
        "lat": "32.523197",
        "lon": "-94.733734"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longkou, China",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "CN",
        "zmw": "00000.1.54753",
        "tz": "Asia/Shanghai",
        "tzs": "CST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.54753",
        "ll": "37.619999 120.320000",
        "lat": "37.619999",
        "lon": "120.320000"
    },
    {
        "name": "Long Eaton, United Kingdom",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "GB",
        "zmw": "00000.30.03418",
        "tz": "Europe/London",
        "tzs": "BST",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.30.03418",
        "ll": "52.900002 -1.266667",
        "lat": "52.900002",
        "lon": "-1.266667"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longview, Washington",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "US",
        "zmw": "98632.1.99999",
        "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "tzs": "PDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:98632.1.99999",
        "ll": "46.181339 -123.061798",
        "lat": "46.181339",
        "lon": "-123.061798"
    },
    {
        "name": "Long Beach, New York",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "US",
        "zmw": "11561.1.99999",
        "tz": "America/New_York",
        "tzs": "EDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:11561.1.99999",
        "ll": "40.587124 -73.665718",
        "lat": "40.587124",
        "lon": "-73.665718"
    },
    {
        "name": "Long Branch, New Jersey",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "US",
        "zmw": "07740.1.99999",
        "tz": "America/New_York",
        "tzs": "EDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:07740.1.99999",
        "ll": "40.294498 -73.995178",
        "lat": "40.294498",
        "lon": "-73.995178"
    },
    {
        "name": "Londonderry, New Hampshire",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "US",
        "zmw": "03038.2.99999",
        "tz": "America/New_York",
        "tzs": "EDT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:03038.2.99999",
        "ll": "42.888672 -71.299515",
        "lat": "42.888672",
        "lon": "-71.299515"
    },
    {
        "name": "Longonjo, Angola",
        "type": "city",
        "c": "AO",
        "zmw": "00000.9.66318",
        "tz": "Africa/Luanda",
        "tzs": "WAT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.9.66318",
        "ll": "-12.906667 15.253333",
        "lat": "-12.906667",
        "lon": "15.253333"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
println(json)
```

Your `json` variable is an `NSDictionary` (because of the `as! NSDictionary`), so the output is correct.
If you `println(data)` you should get the original json string in the right format.